# swift firestore see if data exists and if not create it, or if exists set to true or false

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am checking the database to see if a key value pair such as `Plumber: true` or `Electrician: true` exists.

If it doesn't exist at all I want to create a new key value pair of:

(for example) `Plumber: true`

though if it does exist and it is true i want to set to false or if it does exist and if false i would like to set it to true

My code is in the `did select row` function

the variable "serviceType" comes from the label.text at cell for row

**I return a dictionary from the current user's data in firebase**

```
  let dictionary = document.data()


     let serviceType = dictionary[String(describing: service)]


                if serviceType == nil {

                  // if field doesn't exist create a new field and set to true

 db.collection("Users").document(uid).setData([String(describing: service): true ], options: SetOptions.merge())


 //else if it does exist check if true or false and set to the opposite
                } else if serviceType == true {

              db.collection("Users").document(uid).setData([String(describing: service): false ], options: SetOptions.merge())

                } else if serviceType == false {
   //set to true 

 }
```

**In this line:**

```
       } else if serviceType == true {
```

I am getting the error

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'Bool'

Answer (score 0):

Cast your serviceType variable to Bool:

```
let serviceType = dictionary[String(describing: service)] as? Bool
```